# ERRO System.InvalidOperationException: A sequência contém mais de um elemento

Tags: mvc

Possuo um sistema que funciona em diversas maquinas, porém em uma maquina ocorre o erro:

`A sequência contém mais de um elemento 
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: A sequência contém mais de um elemento

Erro de Origem:

Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

Rastreamento de Pilha:

[InvalidOperationException: A sequência contém mais de um elemento]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4098162
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +40
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider ´

O sistema acessa a seguinte action

string Login = GetUser();

```
        Ramal ramal = db.Ramais.SingleOrDefault(r => r.sCodFunc == Login);

        if (ramal == null)
        {
            Session["UserAdm"] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserAdm"] = ramal.bAdmSist;
        }

        ViewBag.ListaMes = MontaListaMes();
        ViewBag.Area = (from c in db.Area orderby c.sNome select c).ToArray();

        //return View();

        //Exibir os aniversariantes do mês

        string MesAniversario = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM");
        string DiaAniversario = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd");


        //Coloca em primeiro o aniversariante do dia, e em seguida do mes.
        Ramal[] RamalAniver = (from c in db.Ramais
                               where c.sAniversario.Contains("/" + MesAniversario) && c.bAtivo == true
                               orderby c.sAniversario
                               select c
                               ).ToArray();


        RamalAniver = RamalAniver.OrderByDescending(x => x.sAniversario == DiaAniversario 
            + "/" + MesAniversario).ThenBy(x => x.sAniversario).ToArray();


        return View(RamalAniver.ToList());

        //return View(AniverDia.Union(AniverMes).ToList());

    private string GetUser()
    {

        var Aux = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
        return Aux[1];
    }
```

Alguem já viu este problema?

Comment: Atualizando, O erro estava ocorrendo pois na minha consulta, estava retornando mais de um registro em `Ramal ramal = db.Ramais.SingleOrDefault(r => r.sCodFunc == Login);` Att